# How do I reject pushes to a Mercurial server based on a script, without risking a bad pull during that time?

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I'd like to write a script that examines the incoming changesets on a push to a mercurial server and rejects the push if the changesets do not conform to a particular standard.  It seems like my options are the `prechangegroup`, `pre-changegroup`, and `pretxnchangegroup` hooks.  Unfortunately, the `prechangegroup` and `pre-changegroup` hooks do not appear to have access to the incoming changesets, so I would need `pretxnchangegroup`.  But according to the documentation at http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:pretxnchangegroup, this can lead to inconsistent state for people using the repository while the hook is executing:

> "While this hook is running, if other Mercurial processes access this repository, they will be able to see the almost-added changesets as if they are permanent. This may lead to race conditions if you do not take steps to avoid them."

I'm really not crazy about random weirdness happening if someone does a pull while my script is in the process of rejecting a changeset.  Is there another hook that I can use?  If not, what are the "steps to avoid them" that I need to take?  Is there a way I can lock the repository during my hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand the comments for the quoted paragraph, [Meister Geisler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110204/martin-geisler) confirmed some users' observation that the issue was resolved since hg 1.2, such that the not-yet-permanent incoming changesets are not visible, thus will not be pulled.

Comment: Indeed, this is fixed. Btw, did you write my name like that on purpose? :-)

Comment: @Martin Geisler: I hope my tribute doesn't bother you too much :) I'll always bow before the DVCS meisters that is liberating source code everywhere!

Comment: No, I found it quite funny! :-)